# Some new products not showing in homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, products, new-products

I've a site on magento 1.9.2.4, in home page there is a tab for new products, selected from date in product setting.

The strange thing, some product is not showing in home page, even though I set the date as new.

Suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: which date added product not showing, give any one with date.

Answer (score 0):

the possible steps you can take for this problem

1) please check it has valid new start date and end date at backend and time period not expire.

2) if flat tables were enable than reindex the data from `system->index Managment`

3) clear cache and `flush cache storage`.

4) if above steps not solve your problem please check your block code for fetching new products.

5) your block type should be `type="catalog/product_new"`

Comment: Hi, I tryed all the point. But nothing. I have selected over 15 new products (in product page setted the date new from) and showing only 6. Have you other suggest?